# Polygon with texture in mapzen

Tags: mapzen

I use mapzen for drawing vector tiles on client side.

How can I draw polygon with texture?

I have tried few variants such as:

1. Materials
2. Textures
3. Styles

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with using all three of those! I'd look over the [textures](https://mapzen.com/documentation/tangram/textures/) documentation to see the different options for textures in Tangram.

Here's an example:

```
sources:
    mapzen:
        type: TopoJSON
        url: https://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.topojson

styles:
    waves:
        base: polygons
        material:
            diffuse:
                texture: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkowalsky/tangram-hackz/master/img/seigaiha.png
                mapping: planar
                scale: 0.0000003

layers:
    water:
        data: { source: mapzen }
        draw:
            waves:
                order: 1
                color: white
```

Comment: I think it is what i wanted